# logo image doesn't display

Tags: html, css, firefox

i have two html named a.html and b.html,file achive is [here](http://www.filehub.org/files/download/6785/test-menu.tar.gz), the css of logo image is here:

```
.mylogo{
float:left;
position:relative;
padding:9px 0 0 0;
zoom:1;  /* some effect*/
}

.mylogo img{
position:absolute;
top:10px; /* distance between parent element*/
left:0;}   /* set margin*/

.gets-logo-4x{float:left;}
```

after add some css files(for other omitted elements) in b.html, the logo image of b.html can't display in firefox(works in chrome). how to only modify mystyle.css to make it work? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Create a fiddle or post your webpage link

Comment: The link in your post goes to http://www.filehub.org/files/get/xq7oUxPPpi/test-menu.tar.gz. Edit your post with the code for a.html and b.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your bootstrap.min.css line 10

```
img{max-width:100%;vertical-align:middle;border:0;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;}
```

change this into

```
img{vertical-align:middle;border:0;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;}
```

That is remove the maximum width

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, on your file a.html, you didn't include 'bootstrap.min.css'. Your class .container on b.html page has already being taken by the style on bootstrap which has the same class name '.container'. So go change your class name or you can add a new specific style, for example: #header .container